# how to delete angular workspace created in c:\users\username

Tags: angular

accidentally I ran the angular command "ng new client" in my c:\users<username> directory. how can I delete it? I want to create it in my project folder instead.

Comment: simply delete the folder (right click -> delete)
go to the folder you want to create the project in
run ng new client

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just go to `c:\users\username` and then just right click on that folder and delete?

If you navigated into it in your bash, or whatever program, make sure to close that.

Permanently delete with shift+delete

---

You will need to navigate to whatever folder you want it in via your bash, or whatever program you're using for "ng new client"

Comment: This will delete my profile and other application-related data. Is there any better option?

Comment: @AmiyaDas I'm not saying delete the username folder. I am saying delete the folder that your ng new created.